# Azure - should I renew app registration as service principals are set to be expired after an year?

Tags: azure, azure-service-principal

We have registered our Application on Azure using app registration. I understood that App registration is nothing but a service principal with set of permissions assigned.

In Azure, service principals are set to be expired after an year(max 2 years or never) . Does it mean that I need to manually renew the App registration prior to the service principal expiration?

Comment: `service principals are set to be expired after an year(max 2 years)` - Where did you read that?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1014909/maximum-expiration-date-of-an-azure-service-principal-credential-password

Comment: That’s secret expiration and not Service Principal expiration. You can always create a new secret and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gaurav Mantri said, what you should want to express is that the client secret of the application will expire in two years, because there is no such thing as the expiration of the service principal. For the client secret, you can create and use it at any time, and it can also create multiple ones.

[image]